# Why are the arrays null when I'm sending form data using .NET API and React?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, typescript, asp.net-core

DTO looks like this:

```
public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
public int[] Numbers { get; set; }
```

Method Signature:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddSection([FromForm]TheDto theDto)
```

Add the form data in React:

```
const handleSubmit = (data: any) => {
    const formData  = new FormData();

    for(const name in data) {
        formData.append(name, data[name]);
    }

    postService.addSection(formData);
}
```

It's then sent using axios.

Other values go through fine which are not in an array. I've inspected the data being added to FormData and the data is correct, I have 2 arrays, one holding File[], the other holding number[] and the names match that of the DTO so I'm now at a loss. Have I missed something?

I've used the same method on a single image and that's worked fine.

Edit:
If I log data in the above function, `data` has this:

```
{images: Array(2), numbers: Array(3)}
images: (2) [File, File]
numbers: (3) [40, 43, 77]
```

Further edit:
I can see that the issue is that when I'm appending the data, I'm only adding the string value for the arrays. So I think that the 2 issues are making sure I'm appending the data in the arrays properly and in a way that the .NET array understands to bind the data correctly.

Comment: Can you show what is the value of `data`?

Comment: Added data to the post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way of doing this and I'd be happy to listen to any better ways but I changed the way I appended the data for the arrays, it's now working ok.

```
for(const name in data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data[name]) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data[name].length; i++) {
            formData.append(name, data[name][i]);
        }
    } else {
        formData.append(name, data[name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. You can use `Array.isArray()` to check for `data[name]` as alternative of checking by the field name.